# How to secure codeigniter functions in the controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am currently developing something in codeigniter, a project that i need a little more security. (I bought an ssl certificate)

I saw that if i create a function, let's say the one that is called when i submit the account details to register an account, i can access it easy directly calling it.

First of all it looks bad. I wonder also if there is any security concerns i should worry about.

I found on the internet that a way of blocking direct access is to put this in every function:

```
$THE_REFER = strval(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']));
if (!$THE_REFER)
redirect('home');
```

But doesn't look too professional.

Thank you

Comment: Multiple questions in the same question. Also, what do you mean by 'securing' your function?

Comment: Ok sorry i deleted second question. I don't know very well how can someone make any damage. I mean not to be accessed by purpose, only be accessed by the pages that needs them and other things if exists.

Comment: I'm still unclear on what you're trying to achieve by doing it. A public function inside a controller will be accessible to anyone. You can have extra security measures like `if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');` on top of your controller to prevent direct script access to your controller file.

Comment: MonkeyZeus gave a great answer. Note that if you put an underscore before the method (function) name - codeigniter will automatically make that method private - like: function _registerAccount()

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for public vs private functions?

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action="/validate/register">
    <!-- username, password, blah blah blah -->
</form>
```

**PHP (validate.php)**

```
class Validate extends CI_Controller {

    // accessible in URL
    public function register()
    {
        if($this->check_credentials())
        {
            // success message
        }
        else
        {
            // error message
        }
    }

    // accessible only in this class/controller
    private function verify_info()
    {
        // logic to check if info is good
        // work in CSRF token protection
        // return true or false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP Referrer header contains whatever the client wants it to contain.

You could store (**server side**) a timestamp against the session to **record the client has loaded the account details form, then verify this record when you get an account submission**. It is up to you whether this record would be cleared if the user accesses other pages and how long it would remain valid.

There is no single easy solution as your ability to verify the client is limited. You must balance the effort you invest in security with the value of the data (and trust) you seek to protect and the degree to which you are exposed.

Comment: By coding this all yourself, you reduce your exposure to common attacks, but your vulnerabilities may remain hidden from you, and you will be alone in trying to identify and fix the holes when an exploit happens. When you use a more common framework, other people share the same exposure and responsibility.